# using getElementById before Id has been created

Tags: javascript, html

The following code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Orientation Test</title>

<style>
</style>

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<style type='text/css'>

    body {font-family:Helvetica,FreeSans,Arial,sans; font-size:18px;}
    h1 {margin:0; font-size:22px;}
    label {font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; width:50%;}
    #wrapper {width:100%; height:100%;}

 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

 <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Device motion test</h1>
    <p><label for="aX">aX</label><span id="aX"></span></p>
    <p><label for="aY">aY</label><span id="aY"></span></p>
    <p><label for="aZ">aZ</label><span id="aZ"></span></p>

    <p id = "change">0</p>
 </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Javascript file:

```
 var s$ = function(e) {
 return document.getElementById(e);
 };


 if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
 alert('devicemotion supported');
 window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(ev) {
    var acc = ev.accelerationIncludingGravity;
    dmHdlr(acc.x, acc.y, acc.z);
 }, false);
 }
 else {
 alert("devicemotion not supported on your device or browser.");
 }


var lastDM = new Date().getTime();

function dmHdlr(aX, aY, aZ) {
var currDM = new Date().getTime();
//if (currDM < lastDM + 1000) {return;}
lastDM = currDM;

s$('aX').innerHTML = aX ? aX.toFixed(3) : '?';
s$('aY').innerHTML = aY ? aY.toFixed(3) : '?';
s$('aZ').innerHTML = aZ ? aZ.toFixed(3) : '?';


}
```

I don't understand how this code can work. I am using the document.getElementById function before the the element which I want has been created. As I've put the  tag in the header of the HTML file before I declare the id's of certain elements how can this code work? The script runs before the elements have been created but it works?

Thanks

Comment: That `getElementById()` call only happens within a `devicemotion` event; by that time, the document's ready, the IDs exist, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that none of your functions execute until

```
 if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {...
```

is triggered. At that point the body has rendered and the id exists in the DOM, so no problem. You can declare your function first, as long as the id exists when the function is called. In this case, it does.

Comment: Is it considered bad practise for me to put my script tag at the end of my HTML5 files, so that I am sure that I am running code after an ID has been created?

Comment: No, actually it is good practice to link your scripts at the bottom of the body. You can include library links (jQuery.js, etc) in the head, and your custom scripts right before your closing </body> tag.

Comment: Thanks! That makes things much simpler for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can say for Chrome, Firefox and IE9 browsers that all of these follow an order of parsing the html and executing the javascript.

The browser first loads the html and parses all its tags from head of page. In your html, it would parse the title tag then the meta tags followed by style tags etc. It also ***PARSES*** the javascript file that you mention in  but not ***EXECUTE***.

It then builds the DOM hierarchy and sets the CSS properties to the DOM elements.

Finally, when DOM is in place, it executes the javascript.

```
 if (window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
  ...
 window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(ev) {
  ...
 }
```

Thats why your browser executes `if` condition in `main.js` and gets the elements by id, as the elements have already been parsed by your browser.